# Can't receive UDP Datagrams

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, udp, distributed

i have to develop a distributed system that consists in having a chat session by TCP sockets with someone from it's IP address, connected to a server that lists all ips connected for the last 3 minutes to it. alongside with this main feature the app must make requests to every ip to get their name and current state, active, busy or stopped. after sending that request over UDP sockets and, in the other side they must send a reply of that request also over UDP.

EDIT - basically, the application must contact a server that stores the ips that connected to the server for the last minutes. then it must retrieve that ip addresses and contact each one to get it's name and status.

unfortunately i only receive my reply to my request but the other colleagues receive my request.

how can i fix this situation?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given us much information to go on, but my first thought would be firewall or routing issues.  What's the network topology?  Are the server and the properly working client on the same side of a firewall or NAT router, with the other non-working clients on the other side?  Are the UDP replies from the non-working clients making it onto the wire?  Are they arriving at your server, but not being received properly by the server software? (The last few questions could be answered by using a tool like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to see the network traffic leaving the clients and arriving at the server.)

Comment: in the university is quite impossible to communicate because they have a proxy server with restrict porting rules.
at home, i have a wireless router but i also have portable internet with a usb modem.

Comment: @tiago: So is the server on the university network, or one of your machines at home?  What about the working client and the non-working clients?

Comment: the "presence" server is hosted in the university but it can be accessed from any network. the application must connect to that server, receive the ips from that server and make the list to talk with someone later.

Comment: @tiago: That helps!  It might be a good idea to edit your question to include that information -- other people might not notice it down here in the comments.  So it sounds like the problem is not the client<--> "presence server" communication, but the UDP communication between clients once they've gotten the list of IP addresses from the server?  When you say you successfully "receive a reply to my request", is that a client<-->server or client<-->client communication?

Comment: its client <--> client. my client send to 7 ip addresses requesting their info and then those 7 addresses must reply with their name and status